# Refreshing all values in ConcurrentHashMap in intervals (Threadsafe)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap, scheduledexecutorservice

I currently have a couple of ConcurrentHashMaps that all need to be updated every 30 minutes. All of the values must be updated together since the only API I can call is one that gets all of the data and also due to the fact that all of the ConcurrentHashMaps store the same data that is fetched through this API.

Another important key aspect to this is that there might be new key/value pairs which need to be stored in these maps.

I would like to update them all since this call is quite heavy. I tried researching on this and it seems like using a ScheduledExecutorService is a threadsafe way to do this.

Would something like this work? and if it does is it thread-safe?

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
        //Logic to update all ConcurrentHashMaps
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Thanks

Comment: It clearly depends on what you do in "*//Logic to update all ConcurrentHashMaps*"...

Comment: A scheduler just runs code. If that code is thread-safe, so will be the scheduled job. If that code isn't thread-safe ... well, I guess you got it by now. In other words: we can't tell you, because it is your code; and probably way too much code to put into a reasonable question. In general, this might be solved by having some global lock somewhere that protects all your maps; but getting that kind of locking correct and ok regarding performance ... that sounds like a hard task for you.